# Firestore initial data load makes app unresponsive

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app which stores some customer related data. It was working fine but nowadays the app becomes unresponsive on app start.
Upon investigation I learned that because of the huge data set, the Snapshot listeners which I attach to few collections in app start are causing lots of data to load and because of this initial load, my app becomes unresponsive.

Anybody have any solution so as to control the initial data load or avoid it all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to **`filter`** your data before you display it. You can use one of the filtering methods that corespond to your needs.

According to official documentation for [Order and Limit Data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), i recomand you using the `limit()` method. Will solve your start-up problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :-) I'll check this

Comment: And keep me posted.

Comment: Yes i could solvethe issue using this.  Thanks a lot!